# Closed-form for $F(n) = \sum_{d|n} \omega_x(d) $

Tags: proof-verification, closed-form, arithmetic-functions, multiplicative-function

> Given $x\in \mathbb{C}$ let's define the function $$\cases { \omega_x(n)=1, \quad  n=1 \\ \omega_x(n)=x^r, \quad n=p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}\cdots p_r^{a_r}}$$
>
> a) Prove that $\omega_x(n) \colon \mathbb{N} \longrightarrow
> \mathbb{C} $ is multiplicative
>
> b) Develop a closed-form for  $F(n) = \sum_{d|n} \omega_x(d) $

I think I found a closed-form in order to solve the part b) but I am not sure if it is correct.

I know that, given $\omega_x(n)$ multiplicative, $F(n)$ is multiplicative too, so I split it into the $r$ parts of the factorization of $n$ $$F(p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}\cdots p_r^{a_r})= F(p_1^{a_1})F(p_2^{a_2}) \cdots F(p_r^{a_r})$$
$$F(p_1^{a_1})=\omega_x(1)+\omega_x(p_1)+\omega_x(p_1^2)+\cdots +\omega_x(p_1^{a_1})= 1+x+x+\cdots+x=1+a_1x$$

So

$$F(p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}\cdots p_r^{a_r})= \prod_{i=1}^r(1+a_ix)$$

Is it correct?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your answer is correct.